# Two ways binding a datagrid with a SQL Server database table in WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I am really stuck for a while in this issue, and I really can't find a clear solution in the net, I am trying to bind a WPF datagrid to a SQL Server database table via a datatable as shown in code below.

The problem is that by this way I can only achieve a one way binding (read only) so when I try to edit or delete a row in the datagrid the SQL Server table is not updated which is obvious, can anyone provide with a solution for this.

Code behind:

```
conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT*FROM Client", conn);
DataTable tble = new DataTable();

conn.Open();
adapter.Fill(tble);

tableDataGrid.ItemsSource = tble.DefaultView;
conn.Close();
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "binding to database", WPF only knows about .NET objects, nothing more. You already have code for populating a datatable from te DB, now you also need code that takes that datatable and issues the apropriate `INSERT`s/`UPDATE`s/`DELETE`s.

Comment: I said it's a binding via a datatable

Comment: Could you post some xaml? Maybe your `DataGrid` is read only?